# I've asked to speak with you

Tags: idiomatic-language

I ask my boss' assistant if I can talk to my boss. She accepts. I go into my boss' office and say hi and...

***I've asked to speak with you because...***

1. Is this a perfectly natural thing to say?
2. Would ***I've asked to talk to you*** be just as natural?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both are perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are natural, speak and talk are synonyms. In my opinion as an American, "I've asked to talk to you" feels slightly less formal, but only slightly.

Comment: They are synonyms, yes, but there are nuanced differences between them, for example a boss saying to a subordinate: "I need to speak with you" is different to "I need to talk to you" from the perspective of the subordinate. I believe this is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @gotube huh, personally I interpret them pretty much the same, but I'm sure you're right that there can be more nuance. It also likely varies by region, education, what field it is, etc.